# Raphael Clip Image Issue

Tags: javascript, image, raphael, crop

Okay so I know the title is very vague but here is my more specific question. Currently I am trying to avoid having to use PHP and SQL to store the data points from a cropping tool that I am using. The cropping tool gives me the Top Left (x,y) coordinates and the Bottom Right (x, y) coordinates that they would like me to submit to the database for PHP to make a pretty picture out of.

I found Raphael and noticed that they have a clip-rect tool that allows you to clip an image and it will display the clipped image. What I want to do is take that clipped image and fill the Raphael circle with it.

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 500, 400);

        var paperCenter_X = 500/2;
        var paperCenter_Y = 400/2;

        //var circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 60);
        var circle = paper.circle(paperCenter_X, paperCenter_Y, 100);

        circle.attr("stroke", "#000");
        var grabImage = document.getElementById("jelly");

        var src = grabImage.src;
        //alert(src);
        var img = paper.image(src, 10, 10, 800, 600);
            img.attr({"clip-rect":"0 0 100 150"});
        //var newImage = new Image();
        //newImage.src = img.src;
        alert(newImage.src);

        circle.attr({fill: 'url("'+img+'")'});
```

So the stuff I commented out is stuff I tried and is just not working. Ideally what I would like to do is simply fill the circle with img.attr({"clip-rect":"0 0 100 150"}); Any suggestions on how to do this would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt whether its possible with RaphaelJS, but with direct SVG its possible.

Its done with SVG pattern tag.

Try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
    <title>Text Pattern Fill Example</title>
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="600" height="450">
            <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/600/500/" x="0" y="0"
                width="600" height="450" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <path d="M5,50
             l0,100 l100,0 l0,-100 l-100,0
             M215,100
             a50,50 0 1 1 -100,0 50,50 0 1 1 100,0
             M265,50
             l50,100 l-100,0 l50,-100
             z"
          fill="url(#img1)" />    
</svg>
```

Demo here
http://jsfiddle.net/5kJSa/

Original code taken from here http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/path-pattern-fill.svg

Comment: I was able to get it going pretty nicely using php. I suggest that route.

Comment: No probs, I thought you need a Raphael solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Another answer.

Small deviation from your original code.

I used rect with round corners instead of circle and used the fill attribute.

```
<img id="jelly" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" style="display:none;" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 500, 400);

        var paperCenter_X = 500/2;
        var paperCenter_Y = 400/2;

var grabImage = document.getElementById("jelly");
var src = grabImage.src;

paper.rect(0, 0, 200, 200, 600).attr({
    fill: "url("+src+")",
    "stroke-width": 2
});


// Commenting your original code.
/*
        //var circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 60);
        var circle = paper.circle(paperCenter_X, paperCenter_Y, 100);

        circle.attr("stroke", "#000");
        var grabImage = document.getElementById("jelly");

        var src = grabImage.src;
        //alert(src);
        var img = paper.image(src, 10, 10, 800, 600);
            img.attr({"clip-rect":"0 0 100 150"});
        //var newImage = new Image();
        //newImage.src = img.src;
        alert(newImage.src);

circle.attr({fill: 'url("'+img+'")'});

*/

</script>
​
```

Check the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/8XmqM/

A very basic version of the code will look like this

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 500, 500);
paper.rect(0, 0, 200, 200, 600).attr({
    fill: "url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/)",
    "stroke-width": 2
});​
```